# Managed azure storage account via powershell for VM

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create a VM using AZ PowerShell but I get an error.

```
New-AzVM : Using a client owned (un-managed) storage account for boot diagnostics is not supported for VMs.
ErrorCode: OperationNotAllowed
ErrorMessage: Using a client owned (un-managed) storage account for boot diagnostics is not supported for VMs.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : 
+         New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $primaryResourceGroupName -Locati ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

I am wondering

1. how to check if my storage account is managed or unmanaged
2. how to make the storage account to be managed?

Comment: Hello @Node.Js, can you please provide the script you are running in powershell for creating the VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To more specific to your ask

- > 1 . how to check if my storage account is managed or unmanaged

Run the following `cmd` to check whether the VM OS DISK is managed or unmanaged :

```
(get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName NAME -Name yourvm).StorageProfile.OsDisk
```

Here is the sample screenshot with unmanaged disk VM .

[image]

- > 2.how to make the storage account to be managed?

Now we need to stop the VM to convert Unmanaged to managed disk

Run the below cmd to STOP the VM

```
$rgName = "myResourceGroup"
$vmName = "myVM"
Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Force
```

[image]

- Then Run this cmd to convert to Managed disk

  `ConvertTo-AzVMManagedDisk -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMName $vmName`

Here are the reference output of successfully converted :
[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Create VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm) & [Convert Single Instance VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks#convert-single-instance-vms)